# Show new id for newly list when it is pressed

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent, android-listview

I wonder how to show the new list `id` when it is pressed? Currently the new list is showing the old list id instead itself, but when I **close the app and reopen it again, it will display its id**.

Firstly the data will retrieved from `MySQL` and load into android `listView`. (Assume it has only one list only).

```
  ListView listViewUpdate;
  String ID, iD;
  public static final int PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
  public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
  int mClickedPosition;
  String ReceiveProject, ReceiveDescription, ReceiveTimeIn, ReceiveTimeOut;
  Integer ReceiveProgress;
  String myJSON;
  JSONArray details = null;
  TextView totalHours;
  String MiNtimeIn,MaXtimeOut;
  List<DetailsBean> details1=new ArrayList<>();
  CustomBaseAdapter objadapter;

 public void BuildEditDetails(final String ID) { // Assume the ID is foreign key

        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.107.115/Android/CRUD/detailsRetrieve.php?id=" + ID);


                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception squish) {
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                myJSON = result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    protected void showList() {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            details = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Configs.TAG_RESULTS);

            for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);
                String project = c.getString(Configs.TAG_PROJECT);
                String description = c.getString(Configs.TAG_WORKDESCRIPTION);
                int percentage = c.getInt(Configs.TAG_PERCENTAGE);
                String in = c.getString(Configs.TAG_IN);
                String out = c.getString(Configs.TAG_OUT);
                iD = c.getString(Configs.TAG_ID); // its real id
                DetailsBean dbean=new DetailsBean(iD,project,description,percentage,in,out);
                details1.add(dbean);
            }
             objadapter=new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(),details1);
            listViewUpdate.setAdapter(objadapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When pen icon is clicked **(mClickedPosition==-1)**, it will intent to **Activity B** ,and add a new list in **Activity A** `listView`. If list is pressed**(mClickedPosition!==1)**, it shows its id, and intent to **B** for user to edit.

```
    listViewUpdate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    mClickedPosition = position;
                    String iD = details1.get(position).getID();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
                    intent.putExtra("iD", iD);
                    intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
                    intent.putExtra("mClickedPosition", mClickedPosition);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is" + iD + ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);

                }
            });


 @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addDetails:
                mClickedPosition = -1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Edit_Details.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", ID);
               // intent.putExtra("iD", iD);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
                break;
```

**OnActivityResult Activity A**

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                ReceiveProject = data.getStringExtra("project1");
                ReceiveDescription = data.getStringExtra("description");
                ReceiveProgress = data.getIntExtra("progress", 0);
                ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("timeIn");
                ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("timeOut");
                if(mClickedPosition==-1)
                { // add list
                    if(objadapter!=null)
                    {
                        objadapter.addNewItem(iD,ReceiveProject,ReceiveDescription,ReceiveProgress,ReceiveTimeIn,ReceiveTimeOut);
                    }
                }
                else
                {  // update list
                    if(objadapter!=null)
                    {
                        objadapter.changeItem(mClickedPosition,iD,ReceiveProject,ReceiveDescription,ReceiveProgress,ReceiveTimeIn,ReceiveTimeOut);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Finally CustomBaseAdapter**

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DetailsBean>{   // for ListView


    Activity context;
    List<DetailsBean> details;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Activity context,List<DetailsBean> details) {
        super(context, R.layout.retrieve_details, details);
        this.context = context;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public void changeItem(int m,String ID,String Project,String Description,int Percentage,String in,String out)
    {
        DetailsBean obj = new DetailsBean(ID, Project, Description, Percentage, in, out);
        obj.setProject(Project);
        obj.setProgress(Percentage+"");
        obj.setTimeIn(in);
        obj.setTimeOut(out);
        obj.setDescription( Description);
        details.set(m,obj);
        this. notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addNewItem(String ID,String Project,String Description,int Percentage,String in,String out) {
        DetailsBean obj = new DetailsBean(ID, Project, Description, Percentage, in, out);
        obj.setProject(Project);
        obj.setProgress(Percentage+"");
        obj.setTimeIn(in);
        obj.setTimeOut(out);
        obj.setDescription( Description);
        details.add(obj);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

> New list already can added below the previous list, but when I click
>   the new list, it still showing the old list id..How can I make it
>   display its id? Thanks

When come to this class, it retrieve value from MySQL

[image]

When I click 1 list or 2 list, it display their id, (1 and 2)

Now I added a new list , 3 list now

[image]

when I click the third list, it suppose to display 3 but it display 2

Comment: Do you mean, `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't update your listview?

Comment: @Vyacheslav no..I can see a new list added into listView, but when I click the new list, it display the old list id. If I close the app and reopen it again, only it will shows its id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Show new id for newly list when it is pressed

Use `onPostExecute` of `AddMore` class for getting latest id and sending data back to previous Activity.like:

```
@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(String s) { 
 super.onPostExecute(s); 
 loading.dismiss();
 try{ 
  JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
  int latestID=jsonObject.optInt("lastId");
  //call setResult here 
  ....
  returnIntent.putExtra("project1", project1); 
  returnIntent.putExtra("description", description); 
  returnIntent.putExtra("progress", progress); 
  returnIntent.putExtra("timeIn", timeIn); 
  returnIntent.putExtra("iD", latestID);  //<<<
 }catch(Exception ex){

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in adapter `CustomBaseAdapter` class:

```
public List<DetailsBean> getDetails(){
return details;
}
```

in onItemClick

```
  @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    mClickedPosition = position;
                    String iD = listViewUpdate.getDetails().get(position).getID();

//so check id here
....
```

check  `onActivityResult`:

what is `iD` ?? What is value of this variable?

```
objadapter.addNewItem(iD,ReceiveProject,ReceiveDescription,ReceiveProgress,ReceiveTimeIn,ReceiveTimeOut
```

Comment: Does they sound the same things ? I have this in CustomBaseAdpter

Comment: `public DetailsBean getItem(int position) {
        return details.get(position);
    }`

Comment: I use your code and the new list still display the old list id :(

Comment: @Tony , which values are shown in debug mode ? do you see an old list in `onItemClick`?

Comment: ya, I saw it. Check my post again. New value get from Activity B(`Edit_Details` )and return to `onActivityResult` Activity A

Comment: the iD is the real id , ID is foreign key

Comment: @Tony , you passing this parameter. check what is value of `iD`  when you use `addNewItem`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100543/discussion-between-tony-and-vyacheslav).